# Filtering Blogs Posts in Django based on Admin Approved Posts

Tags: python, django

I have made a blog as a project and I have set users to submit posts for the blog directly but I want to direct this post to the admin first for approval before showing on the website. I have added a field to Post model, 'admin_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)'. I also filtered by Post.objects.filter(admin_approved=True), but still nothing happens and posts are published

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "score.html"
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    context_object_name = 'posts'


def score(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.filter(admin_approved=True)
    }
    return render(request, "score.html", context)


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"


class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['caption', 'design']
    template_name = "post_form.html"
    success_url = '/score'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Here is the model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    design = models.ImageField(
        blank=False, null=True, upload_to='new designs')
    caption = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    admin_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("core:post-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

here is the URL:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views
from .views import (HomeView, ItemDetailView, PostCreateView, PostDeleteView,
                    PostDetailView, PostListView, PostUpdateView, checkout)

app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('checkout/', checkout, name='checkout'),
    path('product/<slug>/', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='product'),
    path('score/', PostListView.as_view(), name='score'),
    path('score/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('score/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('score/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('score/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),

]
```

Am I missing a step or is there something I should do?

Comment: You need to provide more details. How are you displaying these posts? Are you saying that somehow you have posts with `admin_approved=False` in your `score()` view? Or do you mean they're showing up in your `ListView`? Can you share your `urls.py` as well, along with which URL it is that you're going to and not seeing filtering applied?

Comment: I have added the urls I am displaying them through ListView, if there are more details you need let me know to fix it

Comment: Check on adding new post, is its entry in table have what values for column admin_approval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never actually filtering the `ListView`:

```py
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "score.html"
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    context_object_name = 'posts'


def score(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.filter(admin_approved=True)
    }
    return render(request, "score.html", context)
```

As you can see, you have a view called `score()` which is not hooked up in your `urls.py`. When you go to `'score/'`, the `PostListView` view function is called, but there you have only specified `model = Post`, so [by default Django gives you back all your Post objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#viewing-subsets-of-objects).

You need to add the following line to `PostListView`:

```py
queryset = Post.objects.filter(admin_approved=True)
```

and possibly delete the `score` view since it's not doing anything any probably causing all this confusion.